# Where does SharePoint Online open's Office documents like word excel etc

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, office-web-apps, office

I know this sounds silly. However am not getting any article / post which explicitly says that 'SharePoint Online will open MS Office documents (word, excel, ppt) in Browser (Office Online)'.

Moreover **looking at the [Compare SharePoint Online options](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans-v2) getting an impression that 'SharePoint Online Option 1' which doesn't include 'Office Applications' will download Office files to client computer.**

Kindly confirm **"Whether SharePoint Online will open's Office documents like word excel etc in Office Online i.e. in Browser or not?"**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office Online View-only functionality is provided for free.

[image]

To see all the features that are included in each plans, view the [detailed service descriptions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx).

In addition, we can set the default open behavior for a document library by using the document library settings page.

1. In the library toolbar, click Library Settings.
2. On the Document Library Settings page, click Advanced Settings.
3. On the Advanced Settings page, in Opening Document in the Browser, select one of the following options:

   •    Open in the client application

   • Open in the browser

   •  Use the server default

Comment: Just to add to this. You can usually also download the file and work on it on your own PC. The Enterprise plans also allow you to download a copy of Office itself and install it locally.